# How to mirror a flipped object? See screenshot

Tags: modeling, modifiers

[image]

How do you mirror an object that is symmetrical but 'flipped'? The only way I found that kinda work is using an array modifier with object offset targeting an empty and just rotate that empty with the merge option turned on. That's how I got the shape in the screenshot but unlink the mirror modifier it's horrible to work with since there is no clipping option. You end up having to tweak one end and than go to the other side of the object to tweak the points that should be merge but aren't any more because you moved the other ones.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Not that I know of. It seems to me that the mirror modifier just needs an upgrade, maybe in a future update we'll get the option to select a mirror plane and flip it like that.